# Align two equation environment blocks

Tags: equations, align

In my latex file I have lots of equations. Some equations are like a set. So I normally used align environment to align my sets of equations. But I am getting lots of white spaces in my document. It figured out that latex is taking the align environment as a single block and tries to fit to the page.Whenever it's not possible they are putting it in the next pages. So I decided to create different blocks for all my equations so that latex can use that blocks to fit to the page. Now the problem is I want to align my equation blocks. How can I do that?

Comment: You can align equation with `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` environment. For more details https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath

Comment: If you add `\allowdisplaybreaks` to the preamble, page breaks will be allowed inside `align` environments.

Comment: As @TorbjørnT. stated, I have found it reallly helpful to set `\allowdisplaybreaks` to either 3 or 4, and then user `\intertext` in the align for smaller pieces of text, that way LaTeX will break the `align` environment in nice ways

Comment: Don't forget that math display environments as `align`, `gather`, `multline` and their starred counterparts can be split between two different pages if you issue the command `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble (after the loading of the `amsmath` or `mathtools` package of course). It doesn't apply the `aligned`, `gathered`, `multlined` and `split` environments, however.